Best Interim Measure for Inaccessible "Crawl Space" Water Management
I have a 100+ year old town home, partly on a stone foundation/7' basement and partly over an inaccessible "crawl space"--0-2 inches of clearance, wood sleepers on grade.
No vapor barrier obviously. Structurally sound. This is under my kitchen (one of those "extensions"/sheds common to houses of the time. Probably added in the 20s?).
Curiously, the crawlspace is divided in half by a brick wall (perpendicular to the basement), one side is relatively dry (abuts a shared alley), and the other side (towards a shared wall with my neighbor) is both sandy and damp. Not sure if the sand was part of a privy, was used as fill, filled an old stairway, or something else entirely. Also not sure if the water is coming from my neighbor's home or from underground.
Obviously the "right way" to fix this is to replace this crawlspace with a slab or properly sized and treated crawlspace, but this situation is under my finished kitchen so want to avoid ripping it up. At least for now.
Hence my issue and this question.
What I've tried:
Running a dehumidifier with the input/output piped to the space, but the airsealing of the building isn't great, so I'm constantly treating new air which means the dehumidifier runs a lot--$$$.
Looking for suggestions on alternatives--should I:

Install a sump pump in the corner of my basement, which is adjacent to the crawlspace. Hope it lowers the water table and dries the sand.

Install a sump pump as above, but also try to drive a perforated pipe under the crawlspace via the adjacent basement, and connect it to the sump pump to try to capture even more water from the sand

Cover as much of the sand as I can with plastic--again, only 0-2 inches here, so it won't be perfect; but continue to run the dehumidifier and just deal with the cost

All of the above

Something else?


Thoughts most welcomed.
I figure this situation can't be all that uncommon, especially outside the US where homes can be much older than mine, but everything I find online outlines the ideal fix (vapor barrier, insulate walls etc) which I can't easily do here.
What is the best interim measure to take until I can properly replace this with something modern and code compliant?
Thanks all!

We can do nothing but guess. Your description is reasonably thorough, but there are unknowns which will remain unknown until you take action. It's a try-and-see situation, not an ask-the-internet situation. Work from least complex & inspensive upward.

Sketches or photos will help us visualize what you can actually lay eyes on.

Sounds like you've done a lot of background work.  Have you determined where the water is coming from?  Is it coming from outside the house, or does it seem to be a high water table?

Sump pump sounds like a lot of work if you're not sure what the root cause of the problem is.
